# EEVEE Does not render my image as i want to have it, procedual generated Shading is rendered in violet

Tags: blender

Ho wo im make eevee show my shading as workbench or cycles do?

Where to upload the .blend file here?

[This is the output i want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AglO6.png)

[This is what EEVEE shows to me as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNqjn.png)

for both results i use the same emission bsdf setup, same keyframe - i use the exact same project for both results the only parameter i changed was instead of usung cycles i was trying to use eevee

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using shaders and not direct output of the color of the image, the lighting in the scene can change to the color of the surface. The eevee project has filters that can be configured in the main tab. They can change tone, brightness, contrast. Also add highlights.

Comment: tanks alot but i wasted my harddrive :s

Answer (score 0):

Can you please upload your blend file to [Pasteall][1] ?
I will go through the file and let you know the issue.

Also, if you have used any images as texture then make sure that you pack all to the blend file from the file menu, in that external data and then "pack all to .blend". Save the file and then upload to pasteall.
[1]: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: i wiped my harddrive its gone :sss than you anyways